# On the three different versions of “Liveness with (0, 1, ∞)-Counter Abstraction”

Tags: reference-request

[Springerlink](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45657-0_9.pdf?pdf=inline%20link) and [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226027974_Liveness_with_01_-_Counter_Abstraction) point to very similar (but not identical) versions, whereas [Pnueli's Website](https://cs.nyu.edu/faculty/pnueli/PXZ02.htm) points to a different one.  Which version is the latest, which is most complete? Is Pnueli's version a preprint or a postprint?  What does “Category A (Research) Paper” mean?

Comment: The conference version (CAV) is the link you see from Springer. It might be missing an appendix with proofs/examples/etc., in case one was submitted. The version on Pnueli's website is likely the same paper, with the appendix, but before the final editing (which is, on the most part, very minor). The latter should be the most complete version.